# Is it worse to go with Samsung 960 EVO instead of Pro version in terms of price to perforamce measure?

Tags: ssd, shared-storage, nvme

We are about to deploy shared storage researching for ultra-fast storage to implement Microsoft SQL Server Failover Cluster (FCI). So far the project goes, we would to start with 500K IOPS and have ability of grows up to 2M IOPS in a year or so, due to the SQL server growing expectations.

For the purpose of the project, we are going to deploy 4-node cluster of Microsoft Storage Spaces Direct (S2D). Microsoft recommends going with NVMe or NVMe + SSD to obtain maximum performance. Therefore, after some research, Samsung SSDs are good to go with. The setup we consider is following: Samsung 960 EVO NVMe + Samsung 960 PRO SSD.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/benchmarking-samsung-nvme-ssd-960-evo-m-2
http://www.storagereview.com/samsung_960_pro_m2_nvme_ssd_review

Would S2D deliver 500k-2M IOPS to SQL FCI if the setup of S2D is Samsung 960 EVO NVMe + Samsung 960 Pro?

Comment: Relevant: [What is the current state (2016) of SSDs in RAID?](https://serverfault.com/q/776564/58408) and [Are SSD drives as reliable as mechanical drives (2013)?](https://serverfault.com/q/507521/58408)

Comment: neither for business

Comment: Jesus - don't use consumer kit for shared-anything, "Hi I'm going to build something that's a single-point-of-failure for my business using the cheapest components! durrr!"

Answer (score 2):

When you are measuring price for performance, it really depends on the performance that you need to have in an application and if you need to for writes, or reads.

IF those are your only options, I would take the one with price for performance after a benchmark of what your application requires.

However if your building this for a business, I would encourage you to use something that would sustain high rates of either read or write, depending on your application.
http://www.samsung.com/us/business/computing/solid-state-drives